# Select Attributes from xml file with php

Tags: php, sql, xml

This my original XML, i want to run sql on it so i can just select one record from but, I've done it successfully, i want to get only record that i want

```
<catalog>
<product>
<programname>Teva Footwear</programname>
<programurl>http://www.teva.com?cid=aff_pr</programurl>
<catalogname>Teva Footwear Product Catalog</catalogname>
<lastupdated>03/25/2013</lastupdated>
<name>Teva Men Tanza Leather Sport Sandals in Brown</name>
<keywords>Teva Men Tanza Leather Sport Sandals in Brown</keywords>
<description>...</description>
<sku>1000183-BRN</sku>
<manufacturer>Teva</manufacturer>
<manufacturerid>1000183-BRN</manufacturerid>
<currency>USD</currency>
<saleprice>85.00</saleprice>
<price>85.00</price>
<retailprice>85.00</retailprice>
<fromprice>Yes</fromprice>
<buyurl>...</buyurl>
<impressionurl>http://www.awltovhc.com/image-6059025-10757671</impressionurl>
<imageurl>...</imageurl>
<advertisercategory>Men</advertisercategory>
<promotionaltext>Fast, Free Shipping and Free Returns!</promotionaltext>
<online>Yes</online>
<instock>YES</instock>
<condition>New</condition>
<warranty>...</warranty>
<standardshippingcost>0.0</standardshippingcost>
</product>
<product>...</product>
<product>
<programname>Teva Footwear</programname>
<programurl>http://www.teva.com?cid=aff_pr</programurl>
<catalogname>Teva Footwear Product Catalog</catalogname>
<lastupdated>03/25/2013</lastupdated>
<name>Teva Men Original Mush Flip Flops in Tread Black</name>
<keywords>Teva Men Original Mush Flip Flops in Tread Black</keywords>
<description>
See what all the hype is about and get yourself a pair of men's Teva Original Mush sandals today! Mush is the ultimate in flip flop foot-forming comfort. The Original Mush features a thicker sole and slightly wider forefoot and heel for a more generous fit.
```

This is I've done so far (of course i found code online)

```
<?php 

// ----------------  The example uses the php 5 "DOM Functions"  to select specific node uding Xpath query ------------------  

$doc = new DOMDocument;                                        // Create a new dom document 
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;                              // Set features 
$doc->formatOutput = true;                                     // Create indents on xml 

$doc->Load('Teva_Footwear-Teva_Footwear_Product_Catalog.xml');                                        // Load the file 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); 
$query = '//catalog/product/sku[. = "1000183-WAL"]';         // The xpath (starts from root node) 
$names = $xpath->query($query);                                 // A list of matched elements 

$Output=""; 
foreach ($names as  $node) { 
   $Output.=$doc->saveXML($node->parentNode)."\n";             // We get the parent of  "<firstname>" element  (the entire "<person>" node and its children) (maybe get 

the parent node directly using xpath) 
                                                                // and use the saveXML() to convert it to string   
} 


echo $Output."<br>\n\n";                                      // The result  

echo "<hr><br><b>Below view the results  as HTML content. &nbsp; (See also the page's HTML code):</b>\n<pre>".htmlspecialchars($Output)."</pre>"; 

?>
```

this is output after this code: (selected record by manufacturerid)

```
<product>
  <programname>Teva Footwear</programname>
  <programurl>http://www.teva.com?cid=aff_pr</programurl>
  <catalogname>Teva Footwear Product Catalog</catalogname>
  <lastupdated>03/25/2013</lastupdated>
  <name>Teva Men Tanza Leather Sport Sandals in Walnut</name>
  <keywords>Teva Men Tanza Leather Sport Sandals in Walnut</keywords>
  <description>Following in the footsteps of our other sports sandals (no pun intended)  the Tanza Leather was built to perform. Featuring our Universal Strapping System with 3 points of adjustment  as well as Shoc Pad&amp;trade; technology  the Tanza Leather gives you a luxurious feel without sacrificing functionality.</description>
  <sku>1000183-WAL</sku>
  <manufacturer>Teva</manufacturer>
  <manufacturerid>1000183-WAL</manufacturerid>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <saleprice>85.00</saleprice>
  <price>85.00</price>
  <retailprice>85.00</retailprice>
  <fromprice>Yes</fromprice>
  <buyurl>http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-6059025-10757671?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.teva.com%2Fwomens-tanza-leather-feminine-sports-sandals%2F737872627089%252Cdefault%252Cpd.html</buyurl>
  <impressionurl>http://www.awltovhc.com/image-6059025-10757671</impressionurl>
  <imageurl>http://www.teva.com/on/demandware.static/Sites-TEVA-US-Site/Sites-masterCatalogTeva/default/v1364225639089/images/large/T0183-WAL_1.jpg</imageurl>
  <advertisercategory>Men</advertisercategory>
  <promotionaltext>Fast, Free Shipping and Free Returns!</promotionaltext>
  <online>Yes</online>
  <instock>YES</instock>
  <condition>New</condition>
  <warranty>Teva has a 1 year warranty against defective materials and/or workmanship</warranty>
  <standardshippingcost>0.0</standardshippingcost>
</product>
```

How ever it's showing whole thing for that record what I want is something like this so i can format according to my needs. 
keywords in meta
price
description 
and photo linked by buy url something like `<a href="$buyurl"><img src="$image_url"></a>`

Comment: During the first extraction, why don't you extract all information you need ? (price, buy_url..)

Comment: I just want the information for given sku number 1000183-WAL there are over 12000 skus in original xml. While I can use "for each" (the only one i know of) i will return the data for whole file, If i can do it for give sku please let me know how,

Comment: this is how it looks like now [link](http://www.lostknowledge.org/test/one.php) and this is what I'm looking for [link](http://www.lostknowledge.org/search/display.php?prodid=B000002ZCI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution using simplexml:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

list($product) = $xml->xpath("//product[sku = '1000183-WAL']");

echo "<a href=\"{$product->imageurl}\"><img src=\"{$product->imageurl}\" /></a>";
```

Comment: thanks it's working almost exactly the way I wanted it to work, however, Page load time is too slow, it it that whole xml file is loading first and then looking for specific information? In my code above results were coming fast but i wasn't able to use links and all that stuff. Please let me know your thoughts on it.

Comment: @KhushwantSingh: yes, it needs to load first before being processed. I have no idea how to speed this up.

Comment: how can I dump data to mysql and then update it everytime xml file is changed? is this the best alternative or we can comeup with something esle?

Comment: @KhushwantSingh: how do you know that the xml has changed? is there a version number?

Comment: no there's no version number only thing I can use I guess is file szie or time stamp.

Comment: Good idea. How do you want to design your table?

Comment: I'll do it manually for one time then I'll use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$programname` and then dump data like INSERT (maybe i'll use UPDATE) INTO $programname for each field, but my problem is still there how to extract data and save it to mysql

Comment: @KhushwantSingh I'd use `foreach ($xml->product as $product)` and build your 'INSERT'-string. set the field-names in mysql exactly as the node-names in the xml-file, makes it easier. Try something, and if you need help, just open a new question and post your code.